# Accessing class method inside eventListener function Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, this

I have a Class names dialog. Inside this class I have a method hide() to hide the dialog box itself and its modal box. But I can't access hide function from "onclick" function. How can I access it?

```
class Dialog{
    constructor(id){
        this._dialogBox = $('.dialog#'+this.id);
        this._closeButton = this._dialogBox.find('span.closedialog');

        this._closeButton.on('click', function(){
            //how to access hide() function from here?
        });

    }
    hide(){
        this._dialogBack.hide();
        this.dialogBox.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question I could not help to notice that it's probably a good idea for `span.closedialog` to be changed to `button.closedialog` (In HTML). This improves HTML semantics and brings significant benefits to usability and accessibility. Try to focus SPAN using only a keyboard TAB key... All this comes for free if using the proper semantics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascripts `this` context changes inside event listeners. You can work around this by adding the this context to a seperate variable:

```
class Dialog{
    constructor(id){
        this._dialogBox = $('.dialog#'+this.id);
        this._closeButton = this._dialogBox.find('span.closedialog');

        const self = this;

        this._closeButton.on('click', function(){
            //how to access hide() function from here?
            self.hide()
        });

    }
    hide(){
        this._dialogBack.hide();
        this.dialogBox.hide();
    }
}
```

As you can see I assign the `this` context to the variable `self`. After that you can access the class context with self.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you

```js
this._closeButton.on('click', this.hide.bind(this));
```

Context of this is different in event listener so you should bind your actual `this` to eventListener context

Answer (score 0):

Change the onclick function's listener to arrow function if you are using es6+.. arrow functions don't override `this`

`````
class Dialog{
    constructor(id){
        this._dialogBox = $('.dialog#'+this.id);
        this._closeButton = this._dialogBox.find('span.closedialog');

        this._closeButton.on('click', () => {
           this.hide();
        });

    }
    hide(){
        this._dialogBack.hide();
        this.dialogBox.hide();
    }
}````
`````